# combine lines (deleting line numbers) to make a paragraph from text file in python

Tags: python

I have some rather unusual pieces of text, where the content looks like so:

```
[1]  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, co
[2]  Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover .
[3]  Limit of Liability and Disclaimer of Warranty: e authors have used their best e orts in preparing this book, and the information provided herein as is. e information provided is sold without warranty, either express or implied.
[4]  Neither the authors nor Cartwheel Web will be held liable for any damages to be caused either directly or indirectly by the contents of this book.
[5]  Trademarks: Rather than indicating every occurence of a trademarked name as such, this book uses the names only in an editorial fashion and to the bene t of the trademark owner with no intention of infringement of the trademark.
```

.. i.e line number in brackets, followed by the line.

Normally, Id do something like this:

```
    fn = "fn.txt"
    with open (fn, "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().strip()
```

.. however, I have got the line number `[1] [2] ..` followed by two spaces which I'd like to delete before storing the value in `data`. I was wondering how I could do this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to split on the first occurrence of whitespace, and take the remainder of each line. So, using your 'fn' file:

```
In [69]: with open('fn') as infile:
    data = [line.strip().split(None,1)[1] for line in infile]
   ....:     

In [70]: data
Out[70]: 
["It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, co",
 "Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover .",
 'Limit of Liability and Disclaimer of Warranty: e authors have used their best e orts in preparing this book, and the information provided herein as is. e information provided is sold without warranty, either express or implied.',
 'Neither the authors nor Cartwheel Web will be held liable for any damages to be caused either directly or indirectly by the contents of this book.',
 'Trademarks: Rather than indicating every occurence of a trademarked name as such, this book uses the names only in an editorial fashion and to the bene t of the trademark owner with no intention of infringement of the trademark.']
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yea, The logic was very simple indeed.. should have thought a bit more :) accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since the line number will presumably be of varying length, but presumably also not contain that "two spaces" pattern that you can rely on to separate the line number from the text, the simplest approach is to break the string apart on that pattern:

```
number, spaces, line = line.partition('  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find first occurrence of two whitespace

```
>>> new_data = ""
>>> with open (p, "r") as myfile:
...    for i in myfile.readlines():
...        new_data += i[i.find("  ")+2:]
```

Comment: line.partition('  ') is also best